# Keyboard Accessible Slide Panel

Tags: jquery, jpanel, accessibility, jquery-events, slidetoggle

In the following code, how can I make my slide panel keyboard accessible? If the panel is open I can see that it tabs through the links, but it doesn't open the panel.  I've tried changing .hover to .click, .keypress etc and even binding it to two events (both hover and click) to no avail.  My scripting talents are minimal unfortunately.  Any help would be appreciated!

**CSS:**

```
/* slide panel */

#sidePanel {width:550px; position:fixed; left:-485px; top:30%;}

    #panelHandle {background-color:#176233; border:solid 1px #fbfbfb; background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #297847, #176233); 
        background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #297847, #176233); background-image:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #297847, #176233); 
        background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #297847, #176233); background-image:linear-gradient(to top, #297847, #176233); height:150px; width:50px; 
        border-radius:0 5px 5px 0; float:left; cursor:pointer;}

        #panelHandle p {-moz-transform:rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); color:#fff; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold; left:-50px; margin:0; padding:0;
            position:relative; top:55%; width:150px;}

    #panelContent{float:left; border:1px solid #333333; width:480px; height:400px; background-color:#fff;}
```

**Script:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#panelHandle').hover (function () {
            $('#sidePanel').stop(true, false).animate({
                'left': '0px'
            }, 900);
        }, function() {
            jQuery.noConflict();
        });

        jQuery('#sidePanel').hover (function () {
            // Do nothing
        }, function() {

            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery('#sidePanel').animate({

                left: '-485px'
            }, 800);

        });
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sidePanel">
            <div id="panelContent">

                <div class="col1 left20" id="taskPane">
                    <br class="clear" />

                    <table title="My Tasks" class="rounded-corners bottom40 cal">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th id="reqNum1" title="Request Number" class="left40">Request #</th>
                                <th id="taskid1" title="Task">Task</th>
                                <th id="dueDat1" title="Due Date">Due</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>            
                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#" accesskey="c">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td headers="reqNum1" class="left40"><a href="#">12345678</a></td>
                                <td headers="taskid1">Task Name</td>
                                <td headers="taskCat">09/03/12</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                <br class="clear" />


                    <div class="col6 small centerText top60">
                        <a href="#"><span class="icon-previous-2 iconsMedL" title="First Record"></span></a> 
                        <a href="#"><span class="icon-previous left60 iconsMedL" title="Page Back"></span></a></div>
                    <div class="centerText pagination">
                                        <a href="#" class="endPipesm">1 </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="endPipesm">2 </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="endPipesm">3 </a>
                                        <a href="#" class="endPipesm">4 </a>
                                        <a href="#">5 </a>
                                    </div>
                    <div class="col6 small centerText"> 
                        <a href="#"><span class="icon-next-2 iconsMedR rightText" title="Last Record"></span></a> 
                        <a href="#"><span class="icon-next iconsMedR right60 rightText" title="Next Page"></span></a></div>

                </div><!-- end tasks and pending requests -->

            </div>

            <div id="panelHandle"><p>My Tasks</p></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: please put this on a jfiddle or something so we can easily see what this creates.

Comment: Ryan,  I put it up on jfiddle.  URL:  http://jsfiddle.net/outlinedspider/h3y72/

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave out some code? Unless I am missing something, I don't see where you are make the green Tasks button/thing.  From what I see that does not get any focus, so you need to allow to have focus.

Once you do that, you need to put an event listener on the taskPane ID to when focus is brought to the button, taskPane is shown. You have to lock it out somehow so when you hit tab again to open up a request #, you will need to play with `focus()`, `focusin()` and `focusout()`.

Comment: Ryan, no that's all the code.  the tab is panelHandle <div id="panelHandle"><p>My Tasks</p></div> and it's all styled in the CSS.  I've tried making it a link and a button (both focusable) to no avail.